# Qualcomm bluetooth solution on Android requests wrong connection parameter causing disconnects

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, qualcomm

I am currently building an Android App and SDK to connect to a custom BLE board. The Android side is expected to be the Peripheral and my board is the Master. Creation of the GATT-Server on the Android side is done, I get my board to connect and pair without a problem. If I just accept all incoming connection parameter updates on the Master-side and don't send out new parameters connection is stable on most phones.

The problem I have discovered now, is that on phones with a Qualcomm Bluetooth solution, the Qualcomm chip will request "invalid" connection parameters by sending ‘Preferred Periodicity’ as 0. This then causes the connection to drop and reconnect every 30sec.

I think this is a bug on the Qualcomm side, since ‘Preferred Periodicity’ should be 0 only if ‘Interval Min’ and ‘Interval Max’ are the same. If ‘Interval Min’ is different from ‘Interval Max’, ‘Preferred Periodicity’ shall not be 0. The QCOM solution build into my device is violating that rule causing the disconnects.

Another Android Phone with a Broadcom Bluetooth solution also requests ‘Preferred Periodicity’ as 0, but has the same 'Interval Min’ and ‘Interval Max’, working without problems.

Has someone an idea on if possible and how to avoid the connection drops on the board side or if there is anything I can do on the Android side to prevent the connection parameter update all together?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a Bluetooth sniffer log or a hci log you could upload?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately only as screenshots:
https://imgur.com/a/m5PbdlX

Comment: So, as I understand it, your board is sending out a connection parameter request and a Qualcomm phone responds with the incorrect parameters, causing your board to send the Reject indication? You can try to send a connection parameter request where min is equal to max... What I don't understand though is who performs disconnection and why after 30 seconds.

Comment: Ok that's an idea, thanks. From what I have seen the Android phone will disconnect because of the connection parameter update timeout. Since the parameter are not correct my board doesn't accept/respond causing the timeout.

Comment: Who is the one really disconnecting? Since reject is sent, that should end the procedure and not cause any timeouts